# Why does EF5 code first use datetime2 when inserting a nullable datetime into the database?

Tags: entity-framework, datetime, ef-code-first, datetime2

I am saving a Cart object to the database that has a nullable datetime. This is the error I get:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
> resulted in an out-of-range value.

There are quite a few stackoverflow posts documenting fixes to this problem. However, when code first is creating the database it will create the field as a DateTime (allow nulls). But for some reason, code first tries to insert using a DateTime2 field.

I am wondering why EF creates the field one way, but inserts using a different type for the same field.

This is the domain object:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Core.Domain.Cart
{
    public partial class Cart : BaseEntity, ILocalizedEntity
    {
        private ICollection<Catalog> _catalogs;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the name
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the zone identifier
        /// </summary>
        public virtual int ZoneId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the brand identifier
        /// </summary>
        public virtual int BrandId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the customer type identifier
        /// </summary>
        public virtual int CustomerTypeId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the date and time of the opening of a cart
        /// </summary>
        public virtual DateTime? OpeningDateUtc { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the date and time of the closing of a cart
        /// </summary>
        public virtual DateTime? ClosingDateUtc { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the entity is online or not
        /// </summary>
        public virtual bool IsOnline { get; set; }

        /* Truncated for relevance */
    }    
}
```

The model:

```
using FluentValidation.Attributes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Telerik.Web.Mvc;


namespace Admin.Models.Cart
{
        [Validator(typeof(CartValidator))]
        public partial class CartModel : BaseNopEntityModel, ILocalizedModel<CartLocalizedModel>
        {            
            public CartModel()
            {
                Locales = new List<CartLocalizedModel>();
                Catalogs = new List<CatalogModel>();
                UnassociatedCatalogs = new List<CatalogModel>();
            }
            [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Carts.Fields.Name")]
            [AllowHtml]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            //Zone dropdown
            [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Carts.Fields.ZoneList")]
            public SelectList ZoneList { get; set; }        //The dropdown with zones
            public int ZoneId { get; set; }                 //The selected value of the dropdown once the form is submitted
            public string ZoneName { get; set; }            //The name of the zone to display in data-grid List view.

            //Brand dropdown
            [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Carts.Fields.BrandList")]
            public SelectList BrandList { get; set; }       //The dropdown with brands
            public int BrandId { get; set; }                //The selected value of the dropdown once the form is submitted
            public string BrandName { get; set; }           //The name of the brand to display in the data-grid List view. 

            //Customer type dropdown
            [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Carts.Fields.CustomerTypeList")]
            public SelectList CustomerTypeList { get; set; }//The dropdown with CustomerType
            public int CustomerTypeId { get; set; }         //The selected value of the dropdown once the form is submitted
            public string CustomerTypeName { get; set; }    //The name of the CustomerType to display in the data-grid List view. 

            [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Carts.Fields.OpeningDateUtc")]
            [UIHint("DateNullable")]
            public DateTime? OpeningDateUtc { get; set; }

            [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Carts.Fields.ClosingDateUtc")]
            [UIHint("DateNullable")]
            public DateTime? ClosingDateUtc { get; set; }

            [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.Carts.Fields.IsOnline")]
            public bool IsOnline { get; set; }
            
            /* Truncated for relevance */
        }

}
```

So both the `OpeningDateUtc` and the `ClosingDateUtc` are of the type DateTime?.

This is how the database gets generated by EF code first:
[image: EF generated table]

The `OpeningDateUtc` and `ClosingDateUtc` are created as a nullable DateTime field.

So why is it when I save using the `IDBContext.SaveChanges()`, the SQL generated for the query is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[Cart]
set [Name] = @0, [ZoneId] = @1, [BrandId] = @2, [CustomerTypeId] = @3, [OpeningDateUtc] = @4, [ClosingDateUtc] = @5, [IsOnline] = @6, [IsReadonly] = @7, [IsPreviewMode] = @8, [CreatedOnUtc] = @9
where ([Id] = @10)
',N'@0 nvarchar(100),@1 int,@2 int,@3 int,@4 datetime2(7),@5 datetime2(7),@6 bit,@7 bit,@8 bit,@9 datetime2(7),@10 int',@0=N'Cart1',@1=7,@2=4,@3=5,@4='2013-01-09 00:00:00',@5='2013-01-18 00:00:00',@6=0,@7=0,@8=1,@9='0001-01-01 00:00:00',@10=1
```

The interesting part being `@4 datetime2(7),@5 datetime2(7)`.

I understand that I could fix this problem by adding a `.HasColumnType("datetime2")` to the cart map, but it doesn't answer why EF5 (and probably older versions) set them to nullable datetime.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `DateTime` type in .NET has the same range and precision as `datetime2` in SQL Server. When EF inserts or updates a `datetime` or `datetime2` column in SQL Server it converts the model property to the type that can hold the whole range of `DateTime` in .NET, that's `datetime2`. Converting into `datetime` would fail if the `DateTime` property is not inside the range of `datetime` in SQL Server.

The problem that causes the exception are, by the way, not the two nullable `OpeningDateUtc` and `ClosingDateUtc` columns, but the `CreatedOnUtc` value which is `'0001-01-01 00:00:00'` in your SQL snippet, i.e. `CreatedOnUtc` is apparently not initialized in your model entity. The earliest date that `datetime` in SQL Server can store is in the year 1750, so year 0001 won't fit into the type (but it would fit into `datetime2`).

So, solution is to either set `CreatedOnUtc` to a valid `datetime` value or - as you know - define the types as `datetime2` in your mapping.

But I agree, there would be less confusion if EF would map `DateTime` properties by default to `datetime2`.

Comment: Thanks, I have got a solution.

Answer (score 11):

The EF Team actually discussed this particular item during one of the design meetings. The decision was to leave the current behavior as is. Here are the [meeting notes](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design%20Meeting%20Notes%20-%20October%2025,%202012) that can give you more context.