# entity framework mapping doesn't insert milliseconds

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using `Entity Framework 6` to map a Table with a "datetime" column mapped on a property like this "`public System.DateTime DATAOPER { get; set; }`"

This is the code first mapping:

```
this.Property(p => p.DATAOPER).HasColumnName("DATAOPER").HasColumnType("datetime").IsRequired();
```

I set the porperty with `DateTime.Now` but the `INSERT` statement generated is:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Tworkdom]([DATAOPER]) VALUES (@0)

parameter name: @0      parameter value: '13/12/2013 12:55:29'
```

It loses milliseconds information. I want instead a `'13/12/2013 12:55:29.999'` for example

Answer (score 1):

It's a mere display issue. If I create a table with two date columns, one with `DateTime` as (database) data type and one with `DateTime2`, I see this insert statement:

```sql
INSERT [dbo].[Users]([Inserted2], [Inserted])
VALUES (@0, @1)
...
-- @0: '13-12-2013 21:25:56' (Type = DateTime2)
-- @1: '13-12-2013 21:25:56' (Type = DateTime2)
```

However, the values in the database are:

```
Id          Inserted2                   Inserted
----------- --------------------------- -----------------------
1           2013-12-13 21:25:56.5023312 2013-12-13 21:25:56.503
```

Comment: It should be `(Type = DateTime)` for the second parameter, right?

Comment: @PeterHansen No, this is what it said (surprised me too).

Comment: Ah ok. Didn't know that. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246426/why-does-ef5-code-first-use-datetime2-when-inserting-a-nullable-datetime-into-th) explains why, in case you're interested.