# Nullable DateTime property in Entity Framework 6 thows exception on save when value is null

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, entity-framework-6

I have defined a Nullable `DateTime`property in one of my classes:

```
public DateTime? ControlDate { get; set; }
```

When using EF 6 CodeFirst to generate the database (SQL Server 2008) from my model I get:

[image: ControlDate null]

The problem is that when I save my instance with `ControlDate=null` I get this exception:

```
conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
resulted in an out-of-range value
```

I have read multiple related posts and articles saying that this usually happens when you 
define a Non-nullable DateTime property and try to save it without setting a valid date before,
and some people suggest setting the property as nullable in case the property value can be null (which is my particular case).

My question is: why is EF trying to set a default date when my property and column type are nullable. Null should be a valid value and should flow all the way to the database without any other conversion in between.

Here a related article: [Conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type results out-of-range value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331779/c-sharp-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type)

EDIT: : [Here is a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246426/why-does-ef5-code-first-use-datetime2-when-inserting-a-nullable-datetime-into-th). very detailed explanation, in case anyone is interested.

**Lessons Learned:**  Just wanted to clarify that after looking closer, I figured out it was an issue on my side. Right before saving my object it was being set to:

```
myObject.ControlDate = new DateTime()
```

Which, while inspected, it displayed the default incompatible date `1/1/0001`. Which is well known to cause this exception. So my conclusions:

- A model declaring a non-nullable `DateTime` property will result in a `datetime`data type in SQL Server.
- An instance of a class declaring a nullable `DateTime`property will be able to save to the DB as null
- **It is very important** to set a valid default date manually (in case <> NULL), otherwise it will set it to 1/1/0001 and throw the exception

Comment: Are you sure it's not because another `DateTime` property?

Comment: change your column type to datetime2(7)

Comment: Please read this once  [DateTime2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server)

Comment: When you inspect the content of your object before your call to `SaveChanges`, does the `ControlDate` property equal `null` or does it equal 1/1/0001?

Comment: @RobEpstein Yes when I inspect it my `ControlDate` property has a NULL value

Comment: @tia There are only other 2 Non-Nullable properties in my object with correct `DateTime` values.

Comment: Changing my `ControlDate`property to `datetime2`seems to work fine @gillesemmanuel

Comment: Entity Framework is the problem. A CLR `DateTime` value maps to SQL `datetime` if the timestamp is within a normal range of values ("modern" dates from 01/01/1753 through 12/31/9999). If it's outside the normal range, as is 01/01/0001, the value is mapped to SQL `datetime2` (01/01/0001 through 12/31/9999). EF leaves it up to _you_ to make sure your value ends up using the correct SQL datatype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, it's actually the SQL Server `datetime2` type that maps directly to .NET's `DateTime` type, so you may need to change the type of your column in SQL Server

Comment: Yes, that seemed to work @Joeb454. Now I'm thinking whether I need to change all my `DateTime` properties to `datetime2`

Comment: That depends on whether you're mapping them directly through to SQL Server, or whether you want to handle mapping in each save. Personally, given the option, I'd change the SQL Server data types, but that then depends on your situation; it may not be practical to make such a change, or may not be possible (e.g. In a more corporate environment)

Comment: I just upvoted this because you saved me. Wish i saw this 2 hours ago!