# entity framework avoid convert datetime to datetime2

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, datetime

I have a column `create_date` store in `datetime`.

When I query by this column, entity framework generate SQL like:

`([Extent1].[create_date] >=  CAST( @p__linq__3 AS datetime2))
AND ([Extent1].[create_date] <=  CAST( @p__linq__4 AS datetime2))`

The `CAST` here is not necessary, and it takes lower performance.

I have tried these:

```
[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> create_date { get; set; }
```

and

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<myClass>().Property(o => o.create_date).HasColumnType("datetime");
}
```

Both don't work.

How to avoid `CAST`?
I want entity framework generate SQL like:

`([Extent1].[create_date] >=  CAST( @p__linq__3 AS datetime))
AND ([Extent1].[create_date] <=  CAST( @p__linq__4 AS datetime))`

I don't think change .edmx: `<Schema .. ProviderManifestToken="2008"` is a good solution.

Comment: This SO should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246426/why-does-ef5-code-first-use-datetime2-when-inserting-a-nullable-datetime-into-th

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana : I want to change datatype in the generate SQL.

Comment: @Yourway - Did you find the answer ? I am here in a similar situation